# How to display title with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`<input type="text" ng-model= "name" title="{{name}}">`//this title shows name what ng-model contains

In the same way...

```
<select title ="{{item.actionId}}" ng-model="item.actionId"> 
<option ng-repeat="action in actionList" value="{{action.ACTION_ID}}">{{action.URL}}</option>
</select>
```

**actionList:-**

```
$scope.actionList = [{
    "ACTION_ID": 39,
    "URL": "/abc"
  }, {
    "ACTION_ID": 59,
    "URL": "/xyz"
  }];
```

Here `item` is the parent list. I am getting title as it's id as the value is id.
Here I want to get the corresponding url. How can I get the url.

Comment: Post your array here

Comment: yes JSON  actionList

Comment: The code looks fine. Just check you have added data to the same controller which you are using.

Comment: yeah This code is fine, But the title is showing the id but not url, I want to show url

Comment: In your value config, you can pass URL instead of Action_Id.

Comment: No, I need to save it's id.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data and the code looks fine, Check the demo below if you have missed anything.

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.actionList = [{
    "ACTION_ID": 39,
    "URL": "/abc"
  }, {
    "ACTION_ID": 59,
    "URL": "/xyz"
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select title ="{{item.actionId}}" ng-model="item.actionId"> 
<option ng-repeat="action in actionList" value="{{action.ACTION_ID}}">{{action.URL}}</option>
</select>
</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what do you neeD?

Comment: yeah, Me also getting the same, But there onMouseOver it is showing it's id, But I want to show it's name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-options` along with `ng-change` to capture the ids and show url on title

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.actionList = [{
    "ACTION_ID": 39,
    "URL": "/abc"
  }, {
    "ACTION_ID": 59,
    "URL": "/xyz"
  }];
  $scope.getValues=function(){
  debugger
    $scope.selectedID=$scope.item.ACTION_ID;
    $scope.selectedURL=$scope.item.URL;
    console.log("selectedId:" + $scope.selectedID );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select ng-model="item" ng-change="getValues()" ng-options="action as  action.URL for action in actionList" title="{{selectedURL}}"> 
</select>
</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what this ng-model contains... either id or url

Comment: It contains the object. Form there you can fetch the id or URL. Why do you want ng-model to contain id when you can capture the whole object and use it to fetch the id?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below code:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="action as action.URL for action in 
 actionList" title="{{item.URL}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ng-option instead of ng-repeat**. always use **track by** clause to set value in option list when creating from object

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select ng-model="item" ng-options="action as action.URL for action in actionList track by action.URL" >
  <option value="">Volvo</option>
     </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some benefit of ng-option: more flexibility in how the <select>'s model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression.
reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance.
increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually